# Problem with Sharepoint REST API CopyTo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Following problem with using ShP 2013 enterprise on premises and ShPDesigner2013:

1. Given a site `http://server/site` which holds two document libraries
   "docs1" and "docs2". Both libraries hold *.docx documents.
2. The task: Create a ShPDesigner2013 workflow (for some reasons I can't use Visual
   Studio) which copies the selected document (`current item`) from docs1
   to docs2.
3. My problem: I have correctly built the request header
   (`Accept - String - application/json;odata=verbose`), but the "Call
   http web service" action with method=POST and
   `http://server/site/_api/web/lists/GetFileByServerRelativeURL('/docs1/test.docx')/copyTo(strNewUrl='/server/site/docs2/test.docx',bOverwrite=true)`
       doesn't work, it cancels with the following error message:

> RequestorId: ad9824d3-039b-698e-615a-71e2f4b554df. Details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["54"],"SPRequestGuid":["45bc2344-b620-4a4a-850b-0d5476b09e4e"],"request-id":["45bc2344-b620-4a4a-850b-0d5476b09e4e"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4841"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Tue, 26 Jun 2018 11:46:32 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure the `http://server/site/_api/web/lists/GetFileByServerRelativeURL('/docs1/test.docx')` call works because you're not really giving it a server-relative url (`/site/docs1/test.docx` in your example).

-> you can easily verify if the file was correctly referenced if it returns valid results in the browser or JSOM call.

Secondly, for strNewUrl also provide a server-relative url (`/site/docs2/test.docx`) => your example had the hostname part "/server" included.

Comment: If I enter `http://server/site/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/docs1/test.docx')?$select=Title` into the browser, it delivers a correct result. However, if entering into the CALL HTPP: `http://server/site/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/docs1/test.docx')/copyTo(strNewUrl=''/site/docs2/TestDocTSG.docx',bOverwrite=true)` it still cancels...

Comment: The copyTo requires a POST which you cannot do by navigating to it with a browser. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileCopyTo

Comment: Also, make sure you provide a valid request digest: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is solved, thanks to the different hints on how to type correctly ...

Comment: @Helimac - how do you fix this?